# BroadcastReceiver not called when app is killed

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My BroadcastReceiver is not being called, when the app is swiped away. It works fine, when its in the foreground/background.
Im trying to create an alarm clock. 
Here is the alarm code:

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmBCReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                   0, myIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10*1000),  pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The receiver class's onReceive method:

```
    Log.i("BCReceiver", "Received");
    Intent startIntent = context
            .getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
    startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startIntent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
    );
    context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

And finally the manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AlarmBCReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" />

<activity
        android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to restart the app, when onReceive(), even if the app was killed. 
I've read that this should work, and I don't understand why it doesn't.

The logger shows nothing if the app is killed, so I think the onReceive method is not called at all. Note that I'm testing on a real device(Xiaomi Redmi 4x). 
The app is written in AndroidStudio.

```
 minSdkVersion 23
 targetSdkVersion 27
```